# Woocommerce - Problem sorting and filtering products with different tax rates by price

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, sort

**Setup (wordpress and woo only; fresh install):**
Prices entered with tax: No, I will enter prices exclusive of tax
Display prices in the shop: Including tax
Display prices during cart and checkout: Including tax
Tax Rates: Standard 23%, Reduced 5%

Product 1: price 100, tax rate standard (23%), front end price 123
Product 2: price 100, tax rate reduced (5%), front end price 105

**Result:**
When sorting products by price I get:
(low -> high): Product 1 (123), Product 2 (105)
(high -> low): Product 2 (105), Product 1 (123)
Tax rate is skipped during sorting?

Similar problem applies to filtering by price. If i set filter to: from 120 to 130. I get both products in the results. So I am assuming filtering doesn’t respect different tax rates. And applies standard tax rate to both products.

Is the only way around this to enter product prices including tax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wasn’t able to find any solution to my problem so I made a simple plugin:

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: calisia-sort-and-filter
 * Author: Tomasz Boroń
 */

//order by; add new options and remove defaults
add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby_options', 'calisia_sort_and_filter::add_new_postmeta_orderby' );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_catalog_orderby', 'calisia_sort_and_filter::add_new_postmeta_orderby' );
//order by; arguments
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args', 'calisia_sort_and_filter::add_postmeta_ordering_args' );
//price filtering
add_action('woocommerce_product_query', 'calisia_sort_and_filter::min_max_price_handler');
//save meta _price_with_tax on every product update
add_action( 'woocommerce_update_product', 'calisia_sort_and_filter::product_save', 10, 1 );
//set meta _price_with_tax for all existing products
//to run: create new page with slug "calisia-add-price-meta" and visit it
add_action( 'get_header', 'calisia_sort_and_filter::add_meta_price_to_all_products' );

class calisia_sort_and_filter{

    //NEW ORDER BY OPTIONS, REMOVING DEFAULTS
    public static function add_new_postmeta_orderby( $sortby ) {
    
        // Adjust the text as desired
        $sortby['price_with_tax_asc'] = __( 'Sort by price: low to high', 'woocommerce' );
        $sortby['price_with_tax_desc'] = __( 'Sort by price: high to low', 'woocommerce' );
    
        //remove default price order by
        unset($sortby['price']);
        unset($sortby['price-desc']);
    
    
        return $sortby;
    }

    //ARGUMENTS FOR NEW ORDER BY OPTIONS
    public static function add_postmeta_ordering_args( $sort_args ) {
        
        $orderby_value = isset( $_GET['orderby'] ) ? wc_clean( $_GET['orderby'] ) : apply_filters( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby', get_option( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby' ) );
        switch( $orderby_value ) {
        
            // Name your sortby key whatever you'd like; must correspond to the $sortby in the next function
            case 'price_with_tax_asc':
                $sort_args['orderby']  = 'meta_value_num'; //meta_value for string
                // Sort by meta_value because we're using alphabetic sorting
                $sort_args['order']    = 'asc';
                $sort_args['meta_key'] = '_price_with_tax';
                // use the meta key you've set for your custom field, i.e., something like "location" or "_wholesale_price"
                break;
                
            case 'price_with_tax_desc':
                $sort_args['orderby']  = 'meta_value_num'; //meta_value for string
                // Sort by meta_value because we're using alphabetic sorting
                $sort_args['order']    = 'desc';
                $sort_args['meta_key'] = '_price_with_tax';
                // use the meta key you've set for your custom field, i.e., something like "location" or "_wholesale_price"
                break;
            
        }
        
        return $sort_args;
    }

    //PRICE FILTERING
    public static function min_max_price_handler($q) {
        global $wpdb, $wp_query;

        if (! $wp_query->is_main_query() || ( ! isset($_GET['max_price']) && ! isset($_GET['min_price']))) {
            return;
        }

        // Remove default Woocommerce min/max price request handler
        remove_filter('posts_clauses', [WC()->query, 'price_filter_post_clauses'], 10);

        $current_min_price = isset($_GET['min_price']) ? floatval(wp_unslash($_GET['min_price'])) : 0;
        $current_max_price = isset($_GET['max_price']) ? floatval(wp_unslash($_GET['max_price'])) : PHP_INT_MAX;

        $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT post_id FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = '_price_with_tax' AND meta_value >= %f AND meta_value <= %f";

        $results = $wpdb->get_results(
            $wpdb->prepare(
                $sql,
                $current_min_price,
                $current_max_price
            ),
            ARRAY_A
        );

        $results = array_column($results, 'post_id');

        if (is_array($results)) {
            $q->set('post__in', $results);
        }
    }

    public static function product_save( $product_id ) {
        $product = wc_get_product( $product_id );
        $price_incl_tax = wc_get_price_including_tax($product);
        update_post_meta( $product->get_id(), '_price_with_tax', $price_incl_tax );
    }

    public static function add_meta_price_to_all_products(){
        if (!is_page('calisia-add-price-meta'))
            return;
    
    
        if(!current_user_can('administrator'))
            return;
    
        global $post;
    
    
        // fetch all products
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'product',
            'posts_per_page' => -1
        );
        $products = new WP_Query( $args );
    
    
        $_pf = new WC_Product_Factory();
    
        if ( $products->have_posts() ){
            while ( $products->have_posts() ){
                $products->the_post();
    
    
               //SAVE
                $product = $_pf->get_product($post->ID);
                $price_incl_tax = wc_get_price_including_tax($product);
                update_post_meta( $post->ID, '_price_with_tax', $price_incl_tax );
                echo "<br>Product id:" . $post->ID . " total price:" . $price_incl_tax;
    
    
                //SHOW
                /*
                $product_attr = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_price_with_tax' );
                // displaying the array of values (just to test and to see output)
                echo var_dump( $product_attr[0] );*/
            }
        }
    
        wp_die();
    }
}
```

How it works?
It adds extra meta value for every existing and new product, called “_price_with_tax”. Value of that meta field is used to filter and sort by price.

Usage:

1. Install and activate
2. Create page with slug “calisia-add-price-meta” and visit it as admin (this will create meta fields for all existing products)
3. Filtering and sorting by price should work as expected now.

Sources:
https://www.skyverge.com/blog/sort-woocommerce-products-custom-fields/
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65360345/override-standard-request-processing-for-min-and-max-price-in-woocommerce-filter

Comment: Thank you @Kazimierz Niewielki it's working for me